# Troubleshooting Delayed ESC Key Detection and Program Exit in Rust CLI Tool with Crossterm and Tokio

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, input, command-line-interface

I am writing a CLI tool which allows connecting to a remote server via SSH, dispatching a command, and streaming its result (in case the command is not instantaneous). I want the user to be able to exit the stream if he wants to by pressing the ESC key. To do this, I use crossterm to set the terminal to raw mode. I then create a mpsc channel and a thread to listen to my keyboard inputs. I create that thread because listening to my keyboard inputs is blocking, and I don't want to block the rest of my app. This thread will send a signal over mpsc if the ESC key is pressed and stop itself.

I then loop over a `tokio::select!` to stop as soon as one of those two async functions stops:

- One awaits the thread signal
- One writes the SSH lines streamed by the remote server (and stops when there is no line remaining)

Unfortunately, this doesn't work: when starting my program with a simple command and then pressing ESC, I need to press it multiple times to get it detected, like if something was blocking my thread from listening, and when it is finally detected, even after writing "finished!", my program doesn't exit immediately, I need to press RETURN a few times. Example output:

```bash
Dispatching: 'for i in {0..16}; do echo 'hello'; sleep 1; done'
Starting the thread
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
key event fired
Detected end
finished!
```

Here's the program source code:

```rs
let mut stdout_reader = FramedRead::new(
    command.stdout().take().expect("Failed to open stdout"),
    LinesCodec::new(),
);
println!("Starting the thread");
enable_raw_mode().unwrap();
let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(32);
thread::spawn(move || loop {
    if let Event::Key(event) = read().unwrap() {
        execute!(
            stdout(),
            Clear(ClearType::CurrentLine),
            Print("key event fired\n"),
            MoveToColumn(0),
        )
        .unwrap();
        if event.code == KeyCode::Esc {
            if let Err(e) = tx.blocking_send(()) {
                eprintln!("Error sending signal: {}", e);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
});

loop {
    tokio::select! {
        _ = rx.recv() => {
            execute!(
                stdout(),
                Clear(ClearType::CurrentLine),
                Print("Detected end"),
                Print("\n"),
                MoveToColumn(0),
            )
            .unwrap();
            break;

        },
        Some(Ok(next_line)) = stdout_reader.next() => {
            execute!(
                stdout(),
                Clear(ClearType::CurrentLine),
                Print(next_line),
                Print("\n"),
                MoveToColumn(0),
            )
            .unwrap();
        }
    }
}

disable_raw_mode().unwrap();
println!("finished!");
```

Why is the ESC key not being detected promptly, and why doesn't the program exit immediately after detection?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If I had to guess, you're blocking the runtime.